# How to configure RmiProxyFactoryBean in @Configuration bean?

Tags: spring

I want to fetch a remote object through SpringRMI:

```
@Configuration
public class RMIConfigBean {

    @Bean
    public NameService nameService() {
        RmiProxyFactoryBean rmi = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
        rmi.setServiceUrl("rmi://localhost:8000/NameService");
        rmi.setServiceInterface(NameService.class);


        return (NameService) rmi.getObject();
    }
}
```

But actually `rmi.getObject()` returns null then the consequent injection for `nameService` failed. Did I miss something? Thanks!

Comment: You need to call `afterPropertiesSet` before calling `getObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As M.Deinum says, I should call `afterPropertiesSet` first.